# Zuul proxy and Spring OAuth redirection issue

Tags: spring-security, oauth-2.0, single-sign-on, netflix-zuul

I'm trying to get a JWT token from third-party SSO server. It requires an additional parameter in the first authorization request, for example

`https://[third-party-sso-server]/oauth2/authorize?client_id=[my-client-id]&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/login&response_type=code&additional_param=[value]`

but Spring Security has the standard redirection URI:
`https://[third-party-sso-server]/oauth2/authorize?client_id=[my-client-id]&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/login&response_type=code&state=[state-value]`
So i cannot add this additional parameter using any filter nor HeaderWriter. And i cannot change the redirect strategy using DefaultRedirectStrategy class.
My code is based on this tutorial https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/#_social_login_manual

`

```
package hello;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.EnableZuulProxy;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import hello.filters.pre.SimpleFilter;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.resource.UserInfoTokenServices;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableOAuth2Client;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter;
import javax.servlet.Filter;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.resource.ResourceServerProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2ClientContext;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestTemplate;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.grant.code.AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableZuulProxy
@EnableOAuth2Client
public class GatewayApplication extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter 
{
    @Autowired
    OAuth2ClientContext oauth2ClientContext;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(GatewayApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public SimpleFilter simpleFilter() {
        return new SimpleFilter();
    }

    private Filter ssoFilter() {
        OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter customFilter = new OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter("/login");
        OAuth2RestTemplate customTemplate = new OAuth2RestTemplate(thirdPartySso(), oauth2ClientContext);
        customFilter.setRestTemplate(customTemplate);
        customFilter.setTokenServices(new UserInfoTokenServices(myResource().getUserInfoUri(), thirdPartySso().getClientId()));
        return customFilter;
    }

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("security.oauth2.client")
    public AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails thirdPartySso() {
        return new AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails();
    }

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("security.oauth2.resource")
    public ResourceServerProperties myResource() {
        return new ResourceServerProperties();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // It doesn't work
        //http.headers().addHeaderWriter(new StaticHeadersWriter("Location","new location"));

        http.antMatcher("/**").addFilterBefore(ssoFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/").authenticated();
    }
}
```

`Spring Boot configuration file:`

```
server:
  port: 8090

zuul:
    routes :
        admin :
            path: /api/admin/**
            url : http://localhost:2222/admin            

security:
  oauth2:
    client:
      clientId: [clientid]
      clientSecret: [secret]
      accessTokenUri: https://[third-party-uri]/oauth2/token
      userAuthorizationUri: https://[third-party-uri]/adfs/oauth2/authorize
      useCurrentUri : false
      tokenName: accessToken
      authenticationScheme: query
      clientAuthenticationScheme: form
    resource:
      userInfoUri: http://localhost:5555/oauth2/token

spring:
  application:
    name: zuul-server

ribbon:
  eureka:
    enabled: false
```

`

Answer (score 2):

I've just fixed the issue by adding additional filter and changed the default redirect strategies

`

```
       ...
        @Override
            public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
                http.antMatcher("/**").addFilterBefore(ssoFilter(),       BasicAuthenticationFilter.class).addFilterAfter(oAuth2ClientContextFilterFilter(), SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.class)
                        .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/").authenticated();
            }

            public Filter oAuth2ClientContextFilterFilter() 
            {
                OAuth2ClientContextFilter  filter = new OAuth2ClientContextFilter();
                filter.setRedirectStrategy(new CustomRedirectStrategy());
                return filter;
            }
        ...

    public class CustomRedirectStrategy extends DefaultRedirectStrategy {

    @Override
    public void sendRedirect(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, String url) throws IOException {
        super.sendRedirect(request, response, url+"&additional_param=value");
    }

}
```

`